# How to log-out user on onunload event of the page in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having problem on calling page method on onunload event in javascript. Basically I want to log-out the user on unload of a page.I created a page method in server side and call it onunload but it doesn't work.

Here is my page method:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub UPDATE_STATUS()

        Dim userCookie As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("userID").Value

        UPDATE_USER_STATUS(userCookie)

        HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll()

        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear()

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("userID").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("userType").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)

End Sub
```

The procedure 'UPDATE_STATUS' updates the user status to 'Inactive'.

I call the above method on unload event like below:

```
window.onunload=function ()
  {
        PageMethods.UPDATE_STATUS();           
  }
```

How will I make this work?

Thanks in advance.